# Flutter side nav animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I was trying to build to build slack mobile app like side nav where we can swipe right to reveal the drawer and also the main body moves right as drawer opens.

Layout:

Stack
-Drawer()
-Homepage()

On the hamburger icon click, I am using animated position to shift the HomePage() and reveal the drawer.

But how can I implement something like the pageview thing, where first child would be Drawer and second child would be Homepage and I can right to reveal the drawer, but the drawer's width will be only 0.5* viewportfraction so the homepage is also revealed and dimmed.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem and i used Stack to solve it, look at
the example:

```
    Stack(
       children: <Widget>[
           buildPartnerList(context),
           FilterDrawer(),
       ],
   ),
```

in the FilterDrawer i returned one animationBuilder

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animationController,
      builder: (context, widget) => buildFilterDrawer(context, widget),
    );
  }
```

the buildFilterDrawer its something like this

```
Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            width: widthAnimation.value,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
    ...
```

and to make the animation, i have one GestureDetector, when clicked animate my side Bar

```
 _moveFliterDrawerAnimation() {
    setState(() {
      _isExpanded
          ? _animationController.reverse()
          : _animationController.forward();
      _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
    });
  }
```